# Communication child-parent ReactJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm learning react js and now I have a situation that I don't know how to resolve and maybe some of you could help me out.

In my webapplication I have a react component that represents a dropdown to select the language, as follows:

```
class LocaleSwitcher extends React.Component{


constructor() {
    super();
    this.render = this.render.bind(this);
    this.componentDidMount=this.componentDidMount.bind(this);
    this.state = { languages:[] };
}


render(){


    return (<li>{this.props.selectedLanguage}
        <ul className="dropdown">
            {
                this.state.languages.map(function(result){

                    return (<ListItemWrapper key={result.id}  title={result.text} url="language" />);
                })

            }
        </ul>
    </li>);

}

componentDidMount(){
    var component = this;
    $.get('data/languages',function(result){
        component.setState({languages: result});
    });
}

};
```

As you can see I'm displaying the selectedLanguage (by default "english") using props : {this.props.selectedLanguage}

For the li elements I have created another component ListItemWrapper, and the communication parent-child I'm doing it via props:

```
class ListItemWrapper extends React.Component{

constructor() {
super();
this.render = this.render.bind(this);
this.handleClick =this.handleClick .bind(this);
}


 render () {
    console.log("title:" + this.props.title);
    return (<li onClick={this.handleClick}><a href="#">{this.props.title}</a></li>);
}

handleClick () {
    $.get(this.props.url+"?code="+this.props.title,function(result){


/*Insert the code here */

    });
}
};
```

My problem now is that I don't know how to do the communication from child to parent, as once the user selects a language I would like to update the dropdown with the selected language, so what I need is to fill the method handleClick to send to the parent component the selected language and update it, but I don't know how to do it. So far I have tried that with no luck

```
handleClick () {
    $.get(this.props.url+"?code="+this.props.title,function(result){

this.props.selectedLanguage=this.props.title;

});
}
};
```

Any help will be very appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649635/communication-between-reactjs-components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to declare the handle click in your `LocaleSwitcher` component and pass it to the `ListItemWrapper` component same like the selected language you have passed.

you can also pass the events in props.

so your LocaleSwitcher component should look like

```
 handleClick () {
    $.get(this.props.url+"?code="+this.props.title,function(result){


/*Insert the code here */

    });
}
    render(){


    return (<li>{this.props.selectedLanguage}
        <ul className="dropdown">
            {
                this.state.languages.map(function(result){

                    return (<ListItemWrapper key={result.id}  title={result.text} url="language" handleClick={this.handleClick}/>);
                })

            }
        </ul>
    </li>);

}
```

and your ListItemWrapper component look like

```
     render () {
    console.log("title:" + this.props.title);
    return (<li onClick={this.props.handleClick}><a href="#">{this.props.title}</a></li>);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of, move your handleClick method to LocaleSwitcher.

Then in your render method in LocaleSwitcher do:

```
render(){
    return (<li>{this.props.selectedLanguage}
        <ul className="dropdown">
            {
                this.state.languages.map(function(result,i){

                    return (<ListItemWrapper key={result.id}  title={result.text} onclick={this.handleClick.bind(this,i)} url="language" />);
                })

            }
        </ul>
    </li>);
}
```

Notice the bind, and the "i" variable in the map function.

Then your ListItemWrapper should look like this:

```
class ListItemWrapper extends React.Component{

constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.render = this.render.bind(this);
}


 render () {
    console.log("title:" + this.props.title);
    return (<li onClick={this.props.handleClick}><a href="#">{this.props.title}</a></li>);
}
```

The official docs has a little article about this:

https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/communicate-between-components.html